# Bundling @tensorflow/tfjs-node requires mock-aws-s3

Tags: node.js, typescript, tensorflow.js, rollup, rollupjs

I have a node app that uses a worker thread to do some stuff with `tensforflow.js`. When I compile using `tsc`, all is good. It works fine.

However, when I try to bundle with either `esbuild` or `rollup`, I get a handful of errors along these lines when running the bundles:

> node:internal/event_target:1033
>
> process.nextTick(() => { throw err; });
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'mock-aws-s3'
> I have tried installing this package, and the others, but this leads to further problems and I would prefer to eliminate this dependency, which does not occur with `tsc` and not bundling.

Any ideas why these bundling tools might produce this result?